# DDL ON SCHEMA trigger

Tags: eventtrigger

Can anyone please tell me whats going on here...

CREATE TRIGGER afr_alt_trig AFTER ALTER ON SCHEMA
  cols ora_name_list_t;
BEGIN
  IF (ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE') THEN
     select column_name bulk collect into cols from user_tab_cols where table_name = ora_dict_obj_name;
     FOR i IN cols.first .. cols.last LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(cols(i));
     END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
The above trigger is expected to display the list of all the columns in a table after the ALTER TABLE command is executed.

It works just fine when I ALTER a table with column(s) without any constraints.
Ex: Alter Table tab_xxx ADD(nucol char);--FINE

However, if I add a new column with a constraint like
Ex: ALTER TALE tab_xxx ADD(n number NOT NULL);
then this new column is not immediately reflected in the USER_TAB_COLS DD view and the FOR loop above to display the names of all the columns DOESN'T show this NEW column added.

Thanks already.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0